# How does this equation x + y = x & y + x | y hold true ( assuming x, y > 0)?

Tags: c++, bit, bitset

I've recently participated in a code forces contest. In the editorial section of the contest, I got to see one of the beautiful relations between bitwise operators which is x + y = x & y + x | y. I don't know the proof yet. I took a few numbers to see if this equation was true. I got excited to know the proof. I looked it up online and couldn't find any meaningful references. please help me find the proof or at least give me the intuition behind this beautiful equation. Thanks in advance

Comment: The book **Hacker's Delight** by Henry S. Warren Jr. is filled with these kinds of relationships.  For bit twiddlers like myself, the book is a joy.  ("Hacker" is used in the earlier good sense.)

Comment: @Sam Why do you think Computer Science is nothing but "templates, overloading, virtual inheritance, algorithms, containers, iterators, and other core C++ fundamentals"? One might argue that understanding basic concepts such as how numbers are represented in a computer is not that useless to know either.

Comment: Somehow, a long time ago, I managed to understand "how numbers are represented in a computer" without having to figure out puzzles like that. I believe that presenting this subject matter directly is far more useful than attempting to work out this bitwise trick.

Comment: I agree with you on that Voo. I'd like to improve my problem-solving skills in the first place. The website has a lot to offer for learners like me. Anyway, thank you, I appreciate that

Comment: How does "explaining how it works", by "it" meaning this specific equation, helps anyone "understand how they are represented"? "Explaining how it works" requires nothing more than a brief overview of base 2 math.

Comment: Are you sure that this is really the code? cppinsights.io says "error: expression is not assignable". Did you mean "==" instead?

Comment: @WernerHenze What he means was more of a general equation involving bitwise calculation rather than an assignment, and if you have changed it to ==, it should always return true

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you're doing `a + b`.

Notice that swapping i-th digit (counting from the rightmost digit) of `a` with i-th digit of `b` doesn't affect the sum. Example: `123 + 456 == 156 + 423`. This works regardless of the choice of the base, so it works for binary addition too.

Next, notice that the transition from `a + b` to `a&b + a|b` can be done by swapping some of the digits in the way described above (in binary). If `a[i] == 1` and `b[i] == 0`, then swap `a[i]` and `b[i]`; after that, `a` becomes `a&b` and `b` becomes `a|b`. Thus this transition doesn't affect the result.

Comment: that was an elegant proof. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 4):

So, whenever you are trying to figure out bitwise calculations, the easiest way would be make a chart for all situation, especially when there are only so little variables.

```
 A | B | A AND B | A OR B |     A + B     | (A AND B) + (A OR B)
---+---+---------+--------+---------------+----------------------
 0 | 0 |    0    |    0   |   0 + 0 = 0   |     0 + 0 = 0
---+---+---------+--------+---------------+----------------------
 0 | 1 |    0    |    1   |   0 + 1 = 1   |     0 + 1 = 1
---+---+---------+--------+---------------+----------------------
 1 | 0 |    0    |    1   |   1 + 0 = 1   |     0 + 1 = 1
---+---+---------+--------+---------------+----------------------
 1 | 1 |    1    |    1   |   1 + 1 = 2   |     1 + 1 = 2
```

Now you might be able to see:

- if `A == B`, then `A + B` and `A & B + A | B` are essentially the same.
- if `A != B`, then `A & B + A | B` might change the order of the two value, but of course, A+B=B+A, so they are essentially the same as while.

Comment: Note that this formally only proves that the statements holds when A and B are either 0 or 1.

Comment: @idmean You are right that I didn't give a good detail for when A and B are greater than 1. However, note that when both A and B are 1, both expression would give you 2 or 10 (not 0), which means the long expression is capable of carrying over; in the same time, digit-wise, the expression also works. Thus the statement would hold for all A and B

Answer (score 3):

for x and y, you can take apart the bits, add them together, and get the same answer right?
example:

```
0101 (x) + 0110 (y) == (0100 + 0001) + (0100 + 0010)
```

now. reviewing your logical operators:
`a & b` gives you the bits that are in *both* numbers (read: count of 2)
`a | b` gives you the bits that are in *either* number (read: count of ≥1)

so basically, you're taking the bits that are in either number, summing them together:

```
0111 == 0100 (in x, y) + 0010 (in y) + 0001 (in x)
```

you're also taking the bits that are in both numbers (i.e. the bits that you need to count twice), and adding that to the sum:

```
0100 == 0100 (in x, y)
```

so, you end up adding the bits that appear once, once, and the bits that appear twice, twice:

```
0111 (bits that appear once or twice) + 0100 (bits that appear twice)
```